# bat multiple `start` commands with concurrent stdout outputs

Tags: batch-file, concurrency, stdout

I have a batch script that starts multiple other programs (multiple instances of the same) using the `start` command to parallelize the tasks since they are independent.

However the commands output some status messages to `stdout` that gets messed up altogether. Is there any way to ensure that

- a) at least each line is printed without interruption of outputs of
  other tasks  - or -
- b) the output of the processes is collected at first and printed synchronized after they finished? - or
- c) some    other way I have not thought about up to yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the output of each command to its own text file, use `start /wait` on the final command, then read all the text files after.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /L %%I in (1,1,5) do (
    start "" "powershell" -command "(Get-Date) -f ''" ^>output%%I.txt
)
start /wait "" "powershell" -command "(Get-Date) -f ''" ^>output6.txt

for /L %%I in (1,1,6) do (
    type output%%I.txt
    del output%%I.txt
)
```

---

vlad_tepesch commented:

> the last started program is not necessarily the last one that quits

**Edit:**

vlad_tepesch commented:

> ...your mentioned "task list" gives me some idea: monitor the tasklist and wait until the started tasks disappear.

Good idea.  Try this:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /L %%I in (1,1,6) do (
    start "" "powershell" -command "(Get-Date) -f ''" ^>output%%I.txt
)

:wait
tasklist | find /i "powershell" >NUL && goto wait

for /L %%I in (1,1,6) do (
    type output%%I.txt
    del output%%I.txt
)
```

That's just a proof of concept.  If you're spawning different commands, just replace

```js
tasklist | find /i "powershell" >NUL && goto wait
```

with

```js
tasklist | findstr /i "program1 program2 program3 program4 etc" >NUL && goto wait
```

... inserting the name of each of your spawned executables into `findstr`.

---

**old JScript solution:**

More advanced management of asynchronous processes is better handled by Windows Scripting Host (VBScript or JScript).

Well, I suppose if you don't need the applications' console output, then you could invoke `wmic process call create 'command'` and capture the PID with a `for /f` loop, waiting until the PID disappears from the task list.  That'd be a way to accomplish your goal with pure batch.  But there's no graceful way to capture the output of `command` that way.

Instead, it's better to use JScript object to collect the spawned processes with [`WshShell.Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).  Then you can deal with the program output however you like -- writing both to the console and to a log file if you wish, or only to one or the other.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

rem // push list of tasks into jobs file
>"jobs.txt" (
    echo wmic nicconfig where "dhcpserver like '%%.%%'" get macaddress ^| find ":"
    echo ping -n 3 localhost
    echo ipconfig
)

rem // process jobs file with JScript
cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "jobs.txt"
del "jobs.txt"

echo;
echo Done.  That was ossum!

rem // End main runtime
goto :EOF
@end
// begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject'),
    osh = WSH.CreateObject('Wscript.Shell'),
    jobsfile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    jobs = jobsfile.ReadAll().split(/\r?\n/),
    procs = {};

jobsfile.Close();

for (var i=0, end=jobs.length; i<end; i++) {
    procs[i] = osh.Exec('cmd /c ' + jobs[i]);
    WSH.Echo('PID ' + procs[i].ProcessID + ': ' + jobs[i]);
}
WSH.Echo('Working...\n');

// wait for all jobs to complete
while (1) {
    var complete = 0;
    for (var i in procs) if (procs[i].Status) complete++;
    if (complete == jobs.length) break;
    WSH.Sleep(1);
}

for (var i in procs) {
    if (!procs[i].StdOut.AtEndOfStream) WSH.StdOut.Write(procs[i].StdOut.ReadAll());
    if (!procs[i].StdErr.AtEndOfStream) WSH.StdErr.Write(procs[i].StdErr.ReadAll());
}
```

Comment: the last started program is not necessarily the last one that quits

Comment: uhh - thats a bit more i expected to be required for such a "simple" task. But your mentioned "task list" gives me some idea: monitor the tasklist and wait until the started tasks disappear. The tasks can be identified by name and the difference of the tasklists before and after the invocation of the multiple start commands. May be this may work

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure Batch solution that prints complete lines from each parallel process:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem If this program was re-executed to arbitrate output, do it
if "%~1" equ ":ArbitrateOutput" goto %1

rem Execute N parallel instances of other program
for /L %%i in (1,1,4) do (
   start /B "" "cmd /C otherProgram %%i  |  "%~F0" :ArbitrateOutput 2> NUL"
)
goto :EOF


rem Arbitrates concurrent output to screen from parallel processes
:ArbitrateOutput

rem Read a line from our companion parallel process
set "line=:EOF"
set /P "line="
if "%line%" equ ":EOF" exit

rem Try: to set an exclusive lock for unique output
:uniqueOutput
2> lock (
   rem Send the line to the screen and delete it
   echo %line%
   set "line="
)

rem Catch: if the line was not sent, try again
if defined line goto uniqueOutput

goto :ArbitrateOutput
```

For example, with this `otherProgram.bat`:

```
@echo off

rem Get a random number of messages
set /A messages=%random% %% (%time:~-1%+1) + 1
ECHO INSTANCE %1: MESSAGES %MESSAGES%

for /L %%i in (1,1,%messages%) do (
   ping -n 2 localhost > NUL
   echo Greetings from instance number %1
)
exit
```

... this is the output:

```
C:\> test

C:\> INSTANCE 4: MESSAGES 3
INSTANCE 3: MESSAGES 4
INSTANCE 1: MESSAGES 2
INSTANCE 2: MESSAGES 5
Greetings from instance number 2
Greetings from instance number 1
Greetings from instance number 3
Greetings from instance number 4
Greetings from instance number 3
Greetings from instance number 2
Greetings from instance number 4
Greetings from instance number 1
Greetings from instance number 3
Greetings from instance number 2
Greetings from instance number 4
Greetings from instance number 3
Greetings from instance number 2
Greetings from instance number 2
```

This method may lost some data if a parallel process send several lines in the same operation, that is, it works better with single lines separated with a lapse. Also, it stops at the first empty line output from a process. This last point may be fixed, if required.